# Update List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have a list in my program:

```dart
List<'QueryDocumentSnapshot'> postsFeelings = [];
```

Data i am getting in the list is from:

```dart
Query postsQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('postsFeelings').orderBy('createdAt', descending: true).limit(perPage);

QuerySnapshot postsQuerySnapshot = await postsQuery.get();

posts = postsQuerySnapshot.docs; //List of type QueryDocumentSnapshot
```

By far I can use available operations on the list like **get(), add(),addAll()**.

**PROBLEM :**

The problem I am facing is that when I want to update a specific element of the list then it doesn't update:

```dart
void testFunction(String postId) 
{
    var element = postFeelings.firstWhere((element) => element.id == postId);

    //successfully shows the map data in the list
    print('SELECTED ELEMENT : ${element.data()}'); // {'liked' : 0}

    //Here i want to update the 'liked' key to value of 3.
    element.data().update('liked', (value) => 3);
    
    postFeelings.forEach((element) { print(element.data()); });
    //[{liked : 0}, {liked : 0}]

}
```

So the operation does run on the specific element but it doesn't updates the value of the key. Any one knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Show your element class and your .data(), .update() methods

Comment: No need for that now. You cannot just update data in a  LIst of type QueryDocumentSnapshot.
In my case i changed my list to the type of Map<String, dynamic> and added data to it coming from firebase.

After this conversion, the data now updates successfullly as it should be. So anyone having this same issue should not use List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> but instead List<Map<String, dynamic>>.

Comment: @ProblematicDude .data() is the data coming from firebase. .update() is a method to update that data simply because data returned from .data() is of type Map<String, dynamic>.

So basically it was a simple map method to update data but List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> would not update the data.